# If answer is this don't ask this

Tags: java, if-statement, java.util.scanner

So I want to make it so that if you give a specific answer to a question, it skips the other questions.
This is currently my code:

---

```
    System.out.print("How old are you? ");
    int age = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
    System.out.print("Do you already have a scooter license? ");
    String scooter = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Do you already have a car license? ");
    String auto = scanner.nextLine();

    if (age >= 17 && auto.equals("no") || age >= 17 && auto.equals("No")) {
        System.out.println("You can get a car license.");
    } else if (age >= 17 && auto.equals("yes") || age >= 17 && auto.equals("Yes")){
        System.out.println("You can also buy a scooter.");
    } else if (age == 16 && scooter.equals("no") || age == 16 && scooter.equals("No")) {
        System.out.println("You can get a scooter license.");
    } else if (age == 16 && scooter.equals("yes") || age == 16 && scooter.equals("Yes")) {
        System.out.println("You can get a car license next year.");
    } else if (age < 16) {
        System.out.println("When you are 15.5 years old you can do your written exam for a scooter license.");
        System.out.println("And when you're 16 you can get a scooter license.");
    }
}
```

---

So what I want is that when you answer anything under 16 to the first question, that you skip the other 2 questions.

And if you answer 16 to the first question, you skip the 3rd question.

And if you answer 17 or higher to the first question you skip the 2nd question.

Can you help me?

Comment: Put an `if` after the line where you parse and assign `age`.

Comment: You could use [String.equalsIgnoreCase()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)) instead of checking for "yes" and "Yes" (or "no" and "No")

Comment: `age >= 17 && auto.equals("no") || age >= 17 && auto.equals("No")` is the same as `age >= 17 && (auto.equals("no") || auto.equals("No"))`; but maybe you could use `age >= 17 && auto.equalsIgnoreCase("no")`, if you don't really care about accepting "nO" or "NO" too.

Comment: As a note to @EdgeworthWright: Consider analyzing your plan before coding, because in your code you asked all questions first and then process the answers. Your code is the reflection of your plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple way of doing this.  By adding a simple if statement around the other questions.

```
System.out.print("How old are you? ");
int age = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
if(age > 15)
{
    if(age == 16)
    {
        System.out.print("Do you already have a scooter license? ");
        String scooter = scanner.nextLine();
    }
    if(age > 16)
    {
        System.out.print("Do you already have a car license? ");
        String auto = scanner.nextLine();
     }
}
```

If they answer 15 or less it skips both next questions.
If they answer 16 it will only ask them about the scooter.
if they answer above 16 it will skip the scooter and ask about auto.

Answer (score 0):

In first - you can use toLowerCase() method. That any answer will be edited in to lower case, so you not need to check the lower/upper case in the answer (equals"no", equals"No").

Also you may exit from function, using `return` or `System.exit(0);` for exit from project.

You can also use '? :' way, to improve the readability of the code

```
    System.out.print("How old are you? ");
    int age = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
    if (age < 16) {
        System.out.println("When you are 15.5 years old you can do your written exam for a scooter license.");
        System.out.println("And when you're 16 you can get a scooter license.");
        //return; / System.exit(0); - can use this way
    } else  if (age == 16) { //or this
        System.out.print("Do you already have a scooter license? ");
        String scooter = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(scooter.toLowerCase().equals("no") ? 
                          "You can get a scooter license." //if yes
                          : "You can get a car license next year."); //if no
    } else {
        System.out.print("Do you already have a car license? ");
        String auto = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(auto.toLowerCase().equals("no") ? 
                          "You can get a car license." 
                          : "You can also buy a scooter.");
    }
```

Comment: `String.equalsIgnoreCase()` can also be used without having to alter your data.